# cross compile to x86_64 on macos

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

Cmake check command always with option '-arch arm64',but x86_64-linux-musl-gcc does't have this option.
this is my cmake settings

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER x86_64-linux-musl-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER x86_64-linux-musl-g++)

# adjust the default behavior of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search for headers and libraries in the target environment,
# search for programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

......

```
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /opt/homebrew/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-gcc
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /opt/homebrew/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-gcc - broken
[cmake] CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
[cmake]   The C compiler
[cmake] 
[cmake]     "/opt/homebrew/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-gcc"
[cmake] 
[cmake]   is not able to compile a simple test program.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   It fails with the following output:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     Change Dir: /Users/ryan/Desktop/development/go/sectran/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
[cmake]     
[cmake]     Run Build Command(s):/opt/homebrew/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_741f1/fast && /opt/homebrew/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_741f1.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_741f1.dir/build
[cmake]     gmake[1]: Entering directory '/Users/ryan/Desktop/development/go/sectran/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
[cmake]     Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_741f1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
[cmake]     /opt/homebrew/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-gcc   -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_741f1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /Users/ryan/Desktop/development/go/sectran/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
[cmake]     x86_64-linux-musl-gcc: error: arm64: No such file or directory
[cmake]     x86_64-linux-musl-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-arch'
```